# What's the difference? Which of these two is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

I would like to know which sentence among below is correct and how one is different than one another.

1.situation depends learning

2.situation dependent learning

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those is a sentence as they only contain a subject and lack both an object and a verb. However I believe you are asking which one is the correct construction of that subject.

That said, the second one is correct, and here's why.

If you break it down, the words "situation dependent" are really behaving as a single modifier of the noun "learning". Many people would hyphenate the two words as "situation-dependent" to indicate that they're really just a single adjective. "Depends" is a verb rather than an adjective, so it doesn't belong there, whereas "dependent" can behave as an adjective in this situation, so it can be used like this